# Are particles capable of infinite subdivision?

Tags: particle-physics

Are the most fundamental particles, e.g., bosons, fermions, etc., capable of further subdivision? Are they at their most fundamental? Or do we consider them so because we're just not capable of going any further?  theoretically, couldn't any fundamental particle always have some smaller component on which it depends?

Comment: What does "fundamental particle" mean to you?

Comment: Nobody knows, nor could they,  ever. We continually demote particles from the "fundamental" status as we find constituents for them, like quarks and gluons for hadrons.

Comment: Up and down quarks can decay into each other by emission of a W boson, so which of the two quarks is more fundamental? The meaning of this word has changed a lot recently, I am going to try to find a great lecture by L. Susskind that addresses this subject.

Comment: @annav then the muon is not considered fundamental?

Comment: @PatoGalmarini  stand corrected.the particles that are now considered fundamental for the mainstream physics, en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle , have fixed masses and are not composed out of constituents. The muon decays into a neutrino__μ, an e and an antielectron for example, but it is not a bound state of those particles, as far as our mainstream physics observations up to now. non fundamnental particles can be modeled as bound stated of  fundamental ones.

Answer (score 3):

It is rather unlikely that the fundamental particle that we currently have in the standard model of particle physics consist of constituent particles. The last time we found such a substructure for particles was several decades ago when nucleons were found to consist of quarks. The nucleons have masses lying close to the so-called QCD scale. When these nucleons were probed at energy scales that come close to the QCD scale, they started to reveal their substructure. The current fundamental particles have been probed at energy scale much larger than their masses and they have not shown any substructure. Therefore, we are convinced that they do not consist of constituent particles.

Comment: I upvoted this but I think it could be improved by referring to internal structure rather than size.

Comment: Can this fundamental particle be divided in half?

Comment: No, fundamental particles cannot be divided in half.